# show cell value if another cell is true, else go to next row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

It's my table in `Sheet1`:

```
A         B          C            D
------------------------------------------
1        220        John         Good
2        210        Jack         Bad
3        300        Mike         Good
4        473        David        Very Good
```

I want to create a list of Good and Very Good records in `Sheet2`. For example:

```
A         B          C            D
------------------------------------------
1        220        John         Good
2        300        Mike         Good
3        473        David        Very Good
```

Which formula should I use to fill each row? (autofill)

Comment: what's you basis for the decision. What have you tried?

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch: I tried this on B1: `=IF(OR(D1="Good"; D1="Very Good"); B1; "")` but it puts empty string if D1 is bad. And won't go to next row (and check again)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the advanced filter functionality in Excel, and set Sheet2 as the filter location. Data > Sort & Filter > Advanced > Check the "Copy to another location" radio button.

You will need to create criteria for this. In this case, create an additional three rows above your table and set the corresponding columns to:

="=Good" and ="=Very Good"

It will look like this (note that you need the blank row in between the criteria and the data, as well as the column labels for the criteria):

```
A         B          C            D
------------------------------------------
                                 =Good
                                 =Very Good

A         B          C            D
------------------------------------------
1        220        John         Good
2        210        Jack         Bad
3        300        Mike         Good
4        473        David        Very Good
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable Autofilter with <kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>D</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd> or select the Filter button on the Data ribbon while the cursor is in the list. Then use a text filter on Column D to filter with "Contains"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to first two answers (though perhaps a little simpler, if consequently less versatile) but ensuring original data is preserved and with renumbering as indicated in question:

- Copy Sheet1 into Sheet2.
- Select Sheet2 ColumnD.
- Data > Sort & Filter – Filter.
- Click on the down arrow, click on Select All and “Bad”, OK.
- Delete all visible rows except first (ie those numbered in blue).
- Click on Filter.
- Select ‘A1’ and with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> depressed, drag down as far as required.

Answer (score -1):

B1 in sheet2

```
=(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B$1:B$4,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!D$1:D$4="bad",,if(Sheet1!D$1:D$4="",,ROW(Sheet1!B$1:B$4)-Row(Sheet1!B$1)+1)),ROW(Sheet1!B1))),""))
```

C1 in sheet2

```
=(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C$1:C$4,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!D$1:D$4="bad",,if(Sheet1!D$1:D$4="",,ROW(Sheet1!C$1:C$4)-Row(Sheet1!C$1)+1)),ROW(Sheet1!C1))),""))
```

D1 in sheet2

```
=(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!D$1:D$4,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!D$1:D$4="bad",,if(Sheet1!D$1:D$4="",,ROW(Sheet1!D$1:D$4)-Row(Sheet1!D$1)+1)),ROW(Sheet1!D1))),""))
```

Comment: What does *For Show* means? Can you be more explanatory?